# Grep special part of string in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to grep a part of string that has numbers and dots(.) in it.

For example:

```
/home/xar/11.1.0/hez
/uaa/14.0.2.5/grd/pc
```

What i want is only this part of line:

```
14.0.2.5
11.1.0
```

I realized that `cut` command is not enough for this problem.

Comment: use "sed" instead of grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` version:

```
sed -n 's!.*/\([0-9.]*\)/.*!\1!p' input
```

Comment: By adding `r` option (regex), you do not need to escape the `()`: `sed -nr 's!.*/([0-9.]*)/.*!\1!p'`

Comment: @Jotne Just FYI .. `-r` is not specified by POSIX, for example, on Mac (BSD) this answer would have to be modified by using `-E` option. On Solaris, neither `-E` nor `-r` would work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this grep:

```
$ grep -o "[0-9.]*" file
11.1.0
14.0.2.5
```

- `-o` is for "print just the matched part".
- `"[0-9.]*"` matches any combination of numbers and dots.

Comment: that doesn't return anything for me. i tried : echo "/oracle/product/10.2.0/db" | grep -o  "[0-9.]*"

Comment: @AloneInTheDark Works fine for me, what system are you on.  Also type  `grep --help` and see that it has the  `-o --only-matching` option, if not use  `sed` or `awk` option.

Comment: I saw that -o has only matching option.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark strange, it should be fine. What if you store it in a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`, but here `grep` is the correct tool.

```
awk -F/ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/[0-9.]+/) print $i}' file
11.1.0
14.0.2.5
```